# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT calls._id

Tags: android, contacts, android-cursoradapter

I want to query the call log details from phone, my query is like below

```
Cursor groupCur = mcontext.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI,
CallLogAdapter.PROJECTION, Calls.NUMBER + " = " + number, null,Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

CallLogAdapter.PROJECTION contain some fields(columns) of call log.

It works fine, but in below condition it will give force close.

*Condition*:-If dial number starting with * or # (ex: *1234567 or #123457) and number end with *  (ex: 1234567*)

```
**ERROR LOG:**
```

> 10-14 14:54:50.425: INFO/Database(26307): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near  syntax error
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307): Writing exception to parcel
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, number, name, date, duration, new, type FROM calls WHERE (number = *674088888) ORDER BY date DESC
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:330)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider.query(CallLogProvider.java:129)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:174)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:111)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(26307):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(27470): Shutting down VM
>   10-14 14:54:50.429: WARN/dalvikvm(27470): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>   10-14 14:54:50.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-14 14:54:50.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27470): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, number, name, date, duration, new, type FROM calls WHERE (number = *674088888) ORDER BY date DESC
>   10-14 14:54:50.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27470):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
>   10-14 14:54:50.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27470):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
>   10-14 14:54:50.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27470):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
>   10-14 14:54:50.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27470):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
>   10-14 14:54:50.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27470):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:262)

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using it like:

```
Cursor groupCur = mcontext.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI,
CallLogAdapter.PROJECTION, Calls.NUMBER + " ='" + number+"'", null,Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and its works fine. thank you Hiral :)

Comment: Glad to know this.BTW,You should accept the answer if it is useful to you.